# How to show changes in source-code without allowing to see or clone the whole project

Tags: android, ios, git, mobile

I have a slightly complex problem here. I need to show to the client what changes I've done in my source code, like activity in git. But I don't want to allow them to download or clone my project.

If anyone has any ideas, please give some suggestion. FYI, the project is a  mobile app (Android and iPhone).

Comment: Why don't you take a diff and show that?

Comment: but the problem is, changes could be a lot, take much our time to show them one by one. besides there's no guarantee that we going to show the diff. i mean, if through GIT there's no hidden changes in the code. PS, i don't know why it was down-voted.

Comment: Understand the rationale for the question, but somehow feel that you could avoid the situation altogether if there is more of trust between you and the client. It is a debatable topic, though. BTW, I wasn't the one who down-voted it.

Comment: Yes I agree, currently it's based on trust between us and them. but they need some sort of proof that the changes is correct. because it's involve sensitive data and has millions users . fyi, it's banking app. I understand they problem, because we need to go to one layer which is Quality Assurance, and approve by them in order to publish. which is the changes is correct and no hidden code whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) as your Git hosing platform, you can distinguish between the "browse repository" permission which allows to view the whole repo from the web interface and typically also to clone it, and the "view changeset" permission which only allows to see the individual changesets (or commits in this case), e.g linked from an issue or in the activity stream.

You can also use these tools simply as a viewer and continue to host your actual primary repository elsewhere.

Git itself doesn't support your use case. So you could either use the solution above (or some other tool which might have similar functionality) or you write your own tool which takes commits and displays them in a meaningful way.

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the core developers of ChiliProject.*